# Pagenavigation and value passing with afterburner fx in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, afterburner.fx

I'm using [afterburner fx](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/) the DI-framework.
My problem is, that I have a "RootLayout" which is a BorderPane. On the top is a MenueBar, which works and in the center I loaded an other pane on startup. Now I want to be able to click on a button, so that the Center-Pane changes to a new View AND I want to pass a value to the new View/Controller.

My main class:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    initInjector();

    //BorderPane
    RootView appView = new RootView();
    Scene scene = new Scene(appView.getView());
    primaryStage.setTitle("Personalplanung");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Controller/Presenter of my Root

```
public class RootPresenter implements Initializable {

@FXML
private AnchorPane center;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    MainView view = new MainView();
    center.getChildren().add(view.getView());
}

//Doesn't work because it must be static -> AnchorPane can't be static
public void putCenter(FXMLView fxmlView) {
    center.getChildren().add(fxmlView.getView());
}
```

Presenter of the view I want to change to and pass value (e.g. selected person)

```
public class MainPresenter implements Initializable {

@Inject
PersonService personService;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

}   

/**
 * Pseudo display of all persons
 * should switch here to PersoView and pass values
 * gets triggerd by button click
 */
@FXML
private void handlePersonsOverview() {
    personService.all().forEach(person -> {
        System.out.println(person.getVorname());
    });
}
```

All my views are empty but extend the FXMLView (is convention)

```
import com.airhacks.afterburner.views.FXMLView;

public class PersonView extends FXMLView{

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your structure correctly, I think you can solve this with a `ViewModel`:

```
public class ViewModel {

    private final ObjectProperty<Node> mainView = new SimpleObjectProperty(this, "mainView", null);
    public ObjectProperty<Node> mainViewProperty() {
        return mainView ;
    }
    public final Node getMainView() {
        return mainView.get();
    }
    public final void setMainView(Node mainView) {
        this.mainView.set(mainView);
    }
}
```

Now just inject the `ViewModel` wherever you need it. Bind the center of the root to the view model's mainView property, and update the mainView property from your other presenters:

```
public class RootPresenter {
    @FXML 
    private BorderPane root ; // I think you have this?
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane center ; // possibly no longer need this?

    @Inject
    private ViewModel viewModel ;

    public void initialize() {
        root.centerProperty().bind(viewModel.mainViewProperty());
        MainView view = new MainView();
        viewModel.setMainView(view.getView());
    }
}
```

Now any presenter that needs to change the center of your root just needs to do:

```
public class SomePresenter {

    @Inject
    private ViewModel viewModel ;

    @FXML
    public void someHandlerMethod() {
        SomeView someView = new SomeView();
        viewModel.setMainView(someView.getView());
    }
}
```

To pass values to the new presenter, just define the appropriate properties and methods in the presenter and invoke them when you create the new view:

```
public class MainPresenter {
    private final ObjectProperty<Person> person = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "person") ;
    public ObjectProperty<Person> personProperty() {
        return person ;
    }
    public final Person getPerson() {
        return person.get();
    }
    public final void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person.set(person);
    }

    public void initialize() {
        // bind to person as needed ...
        // other stuff as before
    }

    // ...
}
```

and then you can do

```
MainView mainView = new MainView();
MainPresenter mainPresenter = (MainPresenter) mainView.getPresenter();
mainPresenter.setPerson(selectedPerson);
```

Comment: Worked for the navigation, but how can I pass values? Lets say I select a row in "GeneralView" and get redirected to "DetailedView", how can I pass the data (object, row)?

Comment: Yeah, I realized I hadn't answered that; just updated